# Merry Golfmas, Everyone!

Tags: code-golf, date

It's Christmas everybody, and here's a code-golf challenge to celebrate. You need to make a program to print out a present. Specifically, the words "Merry Christmas". BUT, there is a catch: this program must only work if it is the 25th of December. If the code is run on any other day, then the program should crash.

This is Code-Golf, so the answer with the least amount of bytes wins.

Merry Christmas!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, please refer to [the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) if you have an idea for challenges.

Comment: Yeah that was ermmmmm. .. yeah 25th sorry

Comment: Related challenges: [Merry Christmas (and a Happy New Year)](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67721/merry-christmas-and-a-happy-new-year), [Christmas Countdown](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15660/christmas-countdown), and [Is it Christmas?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4106/is-it-christmas)

Comment: _Golfy Codemas_! :)

Comment: You say `the program must crash`. Does exiting without an error count?

Comment: No, it must be a crash. You can't quit the aplication

Comment: Just to be extra clear, does an error count if it stops the application?

Comment: Yes that counts

Comment: @PhiNotPi Those challenges are different. This is not asking for a countdown and does not involve waiting to give output

Comment: I think these challenges are very different as waiting for a date is a completely different operation to checking if it is one

Comment: Are you sure this is [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]? KC questions are normally about compressing a constant output. `Merry Christmas` can't really be compressed, this post is more about date/time verification.

Comment: @Flp.Tkc I know. I didn't choose the tag myself

Comment: 25 of December in what timezone? Local timezone? UTC?

Comment: do I leap years?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Pyke, 21 bytes

```
.dↄґ6C65h*325q/Al
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.d%02%E2%86%84%D2%916C65h%2a325q%2FAl)

```
     C65h*        -   multiply the day by the (current month + 1)
          325q    -  ^ == 325
    6         /   - 6 / ^
.dↄґ              -  load "merry christmas"
               Al - ^.capwords()
```

Or 18 bytes noncompetitive.

```
.dↄґ6Cs6Y1q/Al
```

Exactly the same except for this section:

```
Cs6Y1q 
C      -    get_time()
 s6    -   add 1 week
   Y   -  get day of the year
    1q - ^ == 1
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.d%02%E2%86%84%D2%916Cs6Y1q%2FAl)

Comment: This fails if it's October 30th, does it not?

Comment: @carusocomputing `30 * (10+1)` = 330 not 325

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, <s>55</s> <s>53</s> 46 bytes

<sup>Note: this has only been tested in Google Chrome, program may behave differently from browser to browser (or device to device)</sup>

*2 bytes saved thanks to @ConorO'Brien*

*7 bytes saved thanks to @ETHProductions*

```
alert(/c 25/.test(Date())?"Merry Christmas":a)
```

Exits with `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined` if the date is not `Dec 25`. I'm not really sure if this counts as crashing

```js
alert(/c 25/.test(Date())?"Merry Christmas":a)
```

Comment: How about `.slice(6,10)=="c 25"`?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Thanks! That's smart :)

Comment: @ETHproductions I can't think of any day or month that ends in `c` (`Oct` comes close, but still doesn't satisfy the regex). Thanks for the tip!

Comment: The result of `Date()` is completely implementation dependent. For example, I expect it to vary with the language and location of the machine.

Comment: @Oriol Then I will specify the browser in my answer

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, <s>39</s> 38 bytes, not competing (doesn´t crash)

```php
<?=date(md)-1225?"":"Merry Christmas";
```

or

```php
<?date(md)-1225?die:0?>Merry Christmas
```

or

```php
<?=["Merry Christmas"][date(md)-1225];
```

Comment: Can anyone golf 4 bytes off `date(Lz)%1001-358`? :D

Comment: Does this crash?

Comment: You can leave out `""` in the first code which saves you 2 Byte. If it wasn't for damn leap years, you could save 2 Byte more by replacing `md` by `z` and `1225` by the number of the day of the year of December 25th.

Comment: An alternative: `eval((date(md)^TQZZ).'"Merry Christmas";');` (43 bytes)

Comment: @UTF-8: If I remove the `""`, the ternary result will be `1`, not empty. And right, the damn leap years. This would be shorter for New Years Day.

Comment: @Titus I'm pretty sure I checked. I might be wrong, though, and now checked, again. It prints `-1121`, not `1`, which is great because now we have 3 different results.

Comment: @edc65: Uhm no. Sorry, didn´t catch that part. Ismael´s alternative does.

Comment: @UTF-8: Your´re right. I mostly use the Elvis for boolean values; and that would print `1`. This would print the result of the calculation. and `0104-1225` is 1121.

Comment: @Titus I can't believe I didn't know that operator exists and just learned something new. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, <s>66</s> 63 bytes

Thanks to ideas from JavaScript / ES answers here I managed to squeeze some bytes. Index a dictionary - non-existent keys will raise a `KeyError`. The following code works in local time zone

```
import time;print({1:'Merry Christmas'}['c 25'in time.ctime()])
```

The output format for `ctime` isn't locale-dependent - the format is always ~ `'Sun Dec 25 19:23:05 2016'`. Since only in December does the 3-letter abbreviation end with `c`, it is safe to use `'c 25'in time.ctime()` here.

---

**Previous version:**

This works in UTC time zone. For local time zone one needs to `s/gm/local` for 3 more bytes. For Python 2, one can remove parentheses from `print` for 65 bytes.

```
import time;print({(12,25):'Merry Christmas'}[time.gmtime()[1:3]])
```

The construct throws `KeyError` on other dates:

```
>>> import time;print({(1,1):'Happy New Year'}[time.gmtime()[1:3]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: (12, 25)
```

Comment: Does this crash on other days (it's supposed to)?

Comment: I can't get this one to run as it objects to the tuple as a key [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@5@ZW5BfVKJQkpmbal1QlJlXUq1haKRjZKpppe6bWlRUqeCcUZRZXJKbWKxeGw1SpZeeC6I0NKMNrYxiY///BwA "Python 2 – TIO Nexus"). If you change it to `import time;print{'2512':'Merry Christmas'}[time.strftime("%d%m")]` and label it Python 2 it's still 66 bytes and crashes with a KeyError on dates other than 25 Dec.

Comment: @ElPedro oops :D should have been `1:3`, I copied my test code by accident

Comment: Picked up on that when I borrowed your `gmtime()` idea for my answer. Hope you don't mind :-)

Answer (score 4):

### R, <strike>52 61</strike> 58 bytes

```
`if`(format(Sys.Date(),"%m%d")=="1225","Merry Christmas",)
```

If the current date is not the 25th of December then an error is returned because no third argument is supplied to `if`.

Edit: Fixed a silly error

Comment: Sorry about my little typo. I meant to say 25tg

Comment: This only works this year though!

Comment: @Erresen Ah right, silly mistake. Fixed now though.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>68</s> <s>67</s> 65 bytes

-1 with thanks to @muddyfish

Thanks to @AnttiHaapala for the idea that saved another couple.

```python
import time;print['Merry Christmas'][(12,25)!=time.gmtime()[1:3]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@5@ZW5BfVKJQkpmbal1QlJlXEq3um1pUVKngnFGUWVySm1isHhutYWikY2SqqWgLUqaXnguiNDSjDa2MY2P//wcA)

Throws an IndexError if not 25th Dec.

Non-competing version for 59 bytes as it only works for non Leap years (uses day of year which is 360 this year but 361 in leap years)

```python
import time;print['Merry Christmas'][360!=time.gmtime()[7]]
```

Comment: Can't you save a byte by using a list instead of a tuple?

Comment: @muddyfish Thanks, good catch.

Comment: Nice one, my idea was [2 extra bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/bytes/?e=ascii&t=import%20time%3Bprint%5B%27Merry%20Christmas%27%5D%5Btime%2Estrftime%28%27%25m%25d%27%29!%3D%271225%27%5D) :P

Comment: Thanks. That was also my 67 byte version until I commented on the answer from @AnttiHaapala and thought about `gmtime()` to shave a couple off. I have to admit, I wish there was more I could do with the day-of-year idea though.

Comment: You can save 1 byte with: time.ctime()[6:10]!='c 25'

Answer (score 4):

My first time around here... Started with the best language ever for this job:

## Java, <s>200</s> <s>188</s> bytes (thanks to @Daniel Gray), 186 bytes removing "ln" from print.

```
import java.util.*;public class a{public static void main(String[]r){Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();if(!(c.get(2)==11&&c.get(5)==25)){int i=1/0;}System.out.print("Merry Christmas");}}
```

[Try it here!](https://www.compilejava.net/)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first post, even though java isn't quite the shortest.

Comment: You can change the `Calendar` for `*` and save a few bytes. You could also shorten the name of the `args` parameter in the main method, I think...

Comment: @Daniel Gray, You are absolutely right, thanks!

Comment: Welcome! You can save 10 bytes if you replace "public class" with "interface" and remove the public modifier from main, making it "interface a{static void main..." This, however, will prevent Compilejava from being able to run it online.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
'Merry Christmas'IHh&Z'5U12h=?}Yl
```

This works in [current version (19.7.0)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/19.7.0) of the language. To cause the error, the following code exploits the fact that the logarithm of a string gives an error (this may change in future versions).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@6/um1pUVKngnFGUWVySm1is7umRoRalbhpqaJRha18bmfP/PwA)

#### Explanation

```
'Merry Christmas'  % Push this string
IHh                % Push 3, then 2, concatenate: gives array [3 2]
&Z'                % Get 3rd and 2nd outputs of clock vector: current day and month
5U12h              % Push 5, square, push 12, concatenate: gives [25 12]
=                  % Compare if corresponding entries are equal in the two arrays
?                  % If all entries are equal: do nothing
}                  % Else
  Yl               %   Logarithm. Gives an error when applied on a string
                   % End (implicit). Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 3):

## C# / CS Script <s>106</s> <s>100</s> 99 bytes

99 byte solution

```c#
using System;int i;Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dM")=="2512"?"Merry Christmas":i/0+"");
```

[Try it here!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VNCSxf)

100 byte solution (prefer this one... a bit different)

```c#
using System;int i;Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.AddDays(7).DayOfYear==1?"Merry Christmas":i/0+"");
```

Explained:

```c#
using System;
int i;

// if today plus 7 days is the first day of the year, then it's xmas!
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.AddDays(7).DayOfYear==1
    ? "Merry Christmas"

// otherwise divide i by 0
    : i/0+"");
```

`DateTime.Now.AddDays(7).DayOfYear==1` is one byte shorter than `DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMM")=="2512"` but 1 byte longer than `DateTime.Now.ToString("dM")=="2512"`

Comment: You can use `$"{DateTime.Now:dM}"=="2512"`. `dM` is ambiguous, but not for "2512".

Comment: @Kobi I can't use string interpolation for CS Script :(

Comment: You can if you use LinqPad (e.g. `$"{DateTime.Now:dM}"=="2512"?"Merry Christmas":1/1-1+""` 55 bytes)  =)

Comment: Why `int i` and notjust `1/0`?

Comment: @SeeOneRhino the compiler recognises that as an error and won't compile

Comment: @KennethK. I'll have to try linqpad if it can save me a few bytes!

Comment: @KennethK. Tried Linqpad, but your 55 byte solution doesn't work. `1/1-1` is zero not an error, as the division is done before subtraction, and `1/(1-1)` doesn't compile. It's a nice tool though - thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @Erresen Ah, my mistake. I didn't test thoroughly enough. Tweaked:  `$"{DateTime.Now:dM}"=="2512"?"Merry Christmas":"".Remove(1)` (59 bytes)

Answer (score 3):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 48 bytes

```
~left$$|(_D,5)=@12-25||?@Merry Christmas|\?a(12)
```

Explanation:

```
~             IF
left$$|(_D,5) the date string starts with
=@12-25|      the string "12-25"
|             THEN
?@Me..as|     PRINT "Merry Christmas"
\             ELSE
?a(12)        Print the twelfth index of an undefined array. 
              Since there are only 11 elements in undefined arrays, this 
              results in an index-out-of-bounds error.    
The the IF statement is auto-closed by QBIC.
```

This assumes American `MM-DD` date notation. This would be shorter if I'd finally make a Substring function in QBIC.

Comment: What happens on days that aren't Christmas? Does it crash as it's supposed to?

Comment: @Erresen it does now.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <del>32</del> 21 bytes

Saved 11 bytes thanks to Adnan's string compression :) .

```
1žfže‚12D·>‚Q÷”ÞÙŒÎ”×
```

### Explanation

```
 žfže‚                Push [current month, current day]
      12D·>‚          Push [12, 25]
            Q         Push tmp = 1 if the two arrays are equal, tmp = 0 otherwise
1            ÷        Evaluate x = 1/tmp. If tmp = 0 a division by 0 exception is thrown
              ”ÞÙŒÎ”× Implicitly display "Merry Christmas" x times
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@294dF/a0X2pjxpmGRq5HNpuB2QEHt7@qGHu4XmHZx6ddLgPxJz@/z8A)

I did what came to mind first, so there may be better approaches for this one. But PPCG deserves a Merry Christmas in 05AB1E as well ;) .

Comment: Also, `x` is short for duplicate and double :).

Answer (score 2):

## C#/CS Script, 96 Bytes, Mostly Plagiarized from Erresen

```
using System;Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.AddDays(7).DayOfYear==1?"Merry Christmas":1/0+"");
```

Deletes the `int i` declaration in favor of hard coding the division. I would leave this as a comment but don't have the reputation.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first post! Don't worry about the comment/answer thing, it doesn't matter too much.

Answer (score 2):

## bash + Unix utilities, <s>51</s> <s>49</s> 47 bytes

```
((`date +%m%d`-1225))&&${};echo Merry Christmas
```

*Thanks to @KenY-N for pointing out that the quotes in the echo can be removed, and to @IporSircer for reducing the condition size by 2 bytes.

Comment: That gives me `bash: ${}: bad substitution` error. Also you can drop the quotes from *Merry Christmas* to save two bytes. Furthermore, `[ \`date +%m%d\` = 1225 ]&&echo Merry Christmas` works for me, equalling [my 45 bytes](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104737/63348).

Comment: @KenY-N  The error is intentional: the program is **supposed** to crash on days other than Christmas.  Thank you for mentioning that the quotes in the echo can be dropped; I missed that.

Comment: Oops, missed that requirement! Tested out by changing the date string, and I see now that it doesn't crash. Deleted my answer... But, I have an alternative, so let me update it.

Comment: Try replacing `${}` with `!-` to beat me by one byte. I'll upvote you as you win.

Comment: And now I've saved one more byte, so it's a tie again.

Comment: @KenY-N Thanks, but I'm not going to change ${} to !- since I think the latter will only work correctly on the command line, not in a script (unless you turn history substitution on, which would take additional characters).

Comment: You can still save 2 byte at the beginning and win: `((\`date +%m%d\`-1225))&&`

Comment: Thanks, @IporSircer, I've made the change.  It actually does need && with this variant.  (The condition is true if its numerical value is non-zero, which happens when it's not Christmas.)

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 57 bytes

```
print new Date().format("Md")=="1225"?"Merry Christmas":b
```

Crashes on dates other than 25.12. with `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException` because `b` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>69 77</s>  75 or <s>72</s> 70 Bytes

```
import time
if time.strftime("%d%m")=="2512":print"Merry Christmas"
else:1/0
```

If it doesn't matter if it exits with an error when it is Christmas, then:

```
import time
if time.strftime("%d%m")=="2512":print"Merry Christmas"
1/0
```

EDIT:

Thanks @Flp.Tkc for pointing out that I needed to raise an error

-2 Bytes from @Max for pointing out about removing colons from the strftime function

Comment: It's meant to crash if it's not Christmas, this just exits normally.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes removing the colons --> '%d%m' == '2512'

Comment: @Max OK, thanks for the tip. I hadn't used this function before, so I hadn't thought of doing that

Comment: save another 3 bytes with: time.ctime()[6:10]=='c 25'

Answer (score 1):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked/), 42 bytes

[Try it here!](https://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/stacked/stacked.html)

```
('Merry Christmas')'MMDD'date'1225'=¬#out
```

This creates a single-element array containing namely `'Merry Christmas!'`. After, it puts the date into a string with the month followed by the day. It checks for equality with `'1225'` (Christmas), inverts it with `¬`, then gets that member from the preceding array. If it isn't Christmas, this will error with an index error. Otherwise, it prints `Merry Christmas`. (Change the date in the string to see how it works on other days.)

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 66 bytes

```
@echo off
if %date:~0,5%==25/12 echo Merry Christmas&exit/b
if
```

The trailing newline is significant, as it causes parsing of the `if` statement to fail. You may need to tweak the date check to match your local date format.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 28

```
et[C25]#1="Merry Christmas"/
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=et%5BC25%5D%231%3D%22Merry%20Christmas%22%2F)

**Explanation:**

```
et                   push an array of current [year month day hour ...]
[C25]                push the array [12 25] (C=12)
#                    find the position of the 2nd array within the first one
1=                   compare it with 1, resulting in 1 for 1 and 0 otherwise
"Merry Christmas"/   split "Merry Christmas" into pieces of that length
                      (it crashes if the length is 0)
                     at the end, all the pieces are concatenated
                      and printed automatically
```

Answer (score 0):

### C#.NET, <s>180</s> <s>172</s> 171 bytes

*Saved 8 bytes thanks to Kritixi Lithos*

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Kritixi Lithos, again ;)*

```
namespace System{class P{static void Main(string[] args){var d=DateTime.Today;if(d.Day==25)if(d.Month>11){Console.Write("Merry Christmas!");return;}throw new Exception();}}}
```

Alternative, ungolfed variant:

```
namespace System //In System, so we don't have to use system.
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) //Main function.
        {
            var d = DateTime.Today; //Get Today.
            if (d.Day == 25) if (d.Month == 12) //Day has to be 25th, Month has to be 12nd.
                {
                    Console.Write("Merry Christmas!"); return; //Prints.
                }
            throw new NotChristmasException(); //Errors/Crashes the program.
        }
    }
    class NotChristmasException : Exception { } //Holiday exception, hooray!
}
```

Comment: Can't you give the program a shorter class name?

Comment: You could remove some bytes by changing the "NotChristmasException" to something shorter.

Comment: @FishProHD The `NotChristmasException` is only in the ungolfed variant.

Comment: @KritixiLithos Thanks, changed that.

Comment: Oh, so it is. Sorry!

Comment: Can you throw `new Error()` in c#?

Comment: You can also change the `string[] args` to `string[]a` to save a few bytes, I think (I don't know C#, only Java and I think the same tip can apply for both)

Comment: You might be able to do `if(d.Month>11)` instead to save more bytes (since there are no months past #12)

Comment: @KritixiLithos Thanks alot again!

Comment: *You can also change the string[] args to string[]a to save a few bytes* :)

Comment: `if(d.Day==25&&d.Month>11)Console.Write(...);else throw new Exception()` note combined if statements and removal of braces around the `Console.Write` and replace   `return` with `else`. Also change `var d=DateTime.Now` you can get rid of exception throw with perhaps `args[-1];` after renaming args to `a` so `a[-1];` (this so not identical to divide by zeros used elsewhere)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, <s>122</s> 104 bytes

18 bytes saved, thanks to @raznagul

```
using System;i=>{if(DateTime.Now.AddDays(7).DayOfYear==1)Console.Write("Merry Christmas");else{i/=0;};};
```

It adds 7 days to the current day, and checks if it is the first day of the year, if yes, it displays "Merry Christmas", otherwise it divides by zero.

Comment: The `return` is not necessary. Use `i` instead of `()`.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 46 bytes

```
If[Today[[1,2;;]]=={12,25},"Merry Christmas!"]
```

Comment: `Now` saves 2 Bytes over `Today`

Comment: Also, you need a crash in the False outcome, so I think something like `Quit[]` or `1/0` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 140

```
(let((m(multiple-value-list(decode-universal-time(get-universal-time)))))(if(and(eq(nth 3 m)25)(eq(nth 4 m)12))(write"Merry Christmas")(c)))
```

Crashes with undefined function if the date isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

### awk, 29 bytes (+ length("Merry xmas"))

```
v=1225==strftime("%m%d")||1/0
```

Running it:

```
$ echo Merry xmas | awk 'v=1225==strftime("%m%d")||1/0'
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

Season greeting is piped to `awk`. `strftime` returns month+day (for example `1226`) and if it matches `1225` `$0` record gets outputed. Result of comparison `1225==1226` is placed to `v` var which is used to divide 1 if the date comparison fails.

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 116

Crashes with "Non-exhaustive patterns in function f" if it's not Christmas.

```
import Data.Time
f(_,12,25)="Merry Christmas"
main=getZonedTime>>=print.f.toGregorian.localDay.zonedTimeToLocalTime
```

Unfortunately, there's no function that allows you to just immediately get the time in a useful format, so most of this is converting the date formats.

Answer (score 0):

## bash command line, <s>45</s> <s>48</s> 49 48 bytes

```
date +%m%d|grep -q 1225&&echo Merry Christmas||!-
date +%m%d|grep -q 1225||!-;echo Merry Christmas
```

Similar to [Mitchell Spector's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104609/63348), but use `grep` in silent mode to check for a match, then `&&` will ensure that it only prints on success, and the `||` causes it to look up history with `!-`, which gives me this:

```
-bash: !-: event not found
```

And it stops execution as `!- ; echo foo` demonstrates. The `bash` documentation says that `!-n` refers to the current command minus `n`, so perhaps it is being interpreted as `!-0`, which gives an identical (and non-localised) error message.

Comment: Good idea, but this doesn't crash on days other than Christmas, like it's supposed to, does it?

Comment: It now gives an error on failure.

Comment: This prints an error message but it continues; it doesn't actually crash. If you replace the . with ${} then it will actually crash rather simply printing an error message and going on. I think crashing requires that the program be terminated at that point. You can tell that yours doesn't terminate by putting an extra ";echo x" at the end and seeing that it gets executed. (That's why I used ${} instead of . in my answer.) I don't know if there's some 1- or 2-character sequence you can use that will cause an actual crash.

Comment: @MitchellSpector: I found a 2 character sequence!

Comment: And now back to 48 by switching the logic so I can use `;` instead of `||`.

Comment: !- doesn't work in a program, does it? I think this will only do what you want if you type it from the command line, rather than in a program. (There's probably some setting you can use to turn history on inside a shell script, but that would take additional characters.)

Comment: I've been doing all my testing at the command line, not as a script; I'll highlight that in my title.

Comment: Bash is tricky that way -- there are various things that work differently (by default) in a script vs. from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 69 bytes

```
if Time.now.strftime("%j")=="360";puts "Merry Christmas";else 0/0;end
```

Works in 2016. Doesn't differentiate between normal and leap years, may need to be adjusted for non-leap years.

Answer (score 0):

## ForceLang, 180 bytes

```
set s datetime.toDateString datetime.now()
set t "Dec 25"
def c s.charAt i
def d t.charAt i
set i -1
label 1
set i 1+i
if i=6
 io.write "Merry Christmas!"
 exit()
if c=d
goto 1
z.z
```

(Remember that `datetime.toDateString` is locale-dependent, so this may not work depending on your locale)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 90 bytes

```
using System;Console.Write(new[]{"Merry Christmas"}[DateTime.Now.AddDays(7).DayOfYear-1]);
```

Throws IndexOutOfRangeException if it's not christmas.

[Try it here!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6wbSVV)